# Integers of this form that pass the Fermat Primality test are prime, proof?

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, primality-test, mersenne-numbers

**If an integer, $2p + 1$, where $p$ is a prime number, is a divisor of the Mersenne number $2^p - 1$, then $2p + 1$ is a prime number.**

My argument is that because divisors of the Mersenne number $2^p - 1$ can’t be $< p$ if $p$ is a prime number. Therefore if $2p +1$ is a divisor of $2^p - 1$ it has no divisors as $p$ is $>$ the square root of $2p + 1$. This will therefore make $2p + 1$ a prime number.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: $2p^2+1\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ for any  prime $p>3$.  Indeed, if $n$ is any odd number not divisible by $3$ then $2n^2+1\equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

Comment: If it passes the Fermat primality test then divide it by 3 once and it will be prime. It will only be 2m and to be divisible by 9 it would have to be 6m.

Comment: To decide whether the proof is correct, we have to know what it is trying to prove. You never make a clear statement of what it is that you are trying to prove, you just launch into some argument. Please, state the alleged theorem, clearly, in the body of your question.

Comment: Oh, it’s in there. If an integer, 2p + 1, where p is a prime number, is a divisor of the Mersenne number 2^p - 1, then 2p + 1 is a safe prime and p it’s matching Sophie Germain prime. And at the end in **bold**.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange community! The quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will help you get the most benefit from your time here. Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your equations.

Comment: Seconding Gerry Myerson's concern. It is not at all clear which statement you are trying to prove. The highlighted statements you quoted from WP? Or the statement: *If $p$ is a prime and $2p+1$ is a factor of $2^p-1$, then $2p+1$ is also a prime*? Guessing it's the latter.

Comment: I realize that the term *safe prime* is motivated by applications in cryptography, but using it here actually only manages to confuse. Isn't the objective simply to prove that $2p+1$ is also a prime number?

Comment: And, what is the precise meaning of *Fermat primality test* when applied to $q=(2p^2+1)/3$? Are you assuming that $2^{q-1}\equiv1\pmod q$. Or, are you assuming that $q\mid 2^p-1$? Normally we would think that Fermat test of $q$ says that for some integer $a$ we have $q\mid a^{q-1}-1$. It feels like you should use exponent $p-1$ instead of $q-1$?

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I have edited the post to simplify it to Jyrki Lahtonen’s comment.

Comment: Much clearer (+1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is good, but you should prove that every divisor must exceed $p$.

In general, we can prove that for a prime number $p$ and an odd prime $q$ dividing $2^p-1$ , we must have $p|q-1$

The proof is as follows : Let $k$ be the smallest positive integer with $2^k\equiv 1\mod q$. Because of $2^p\equiv 1\mod q$, $k$ must be a divisor of $p$.

$k=1$ is impossible because this would imply $q|1$. Hence , $k=p$

Because of $2^{q-1}\equiv 1\mod q$ (Fermat's little theorem) we can conclude $p|q-1$

In particular, $2p+1$ , if it divides $2^p-1$ must be prime because every prime factor must be of the form $2kp+1$ with positive integer $k$ , hence there cannot be a prime factor less than $2p+1$

Comment: Or that a prime < p will be a factor of a smaller mersenne number according to fermats little theorem. So if p is not a multiple it will have a remainder if we divide it, because the mersenne Numbers repeat themselves. I.e. take remainder=0 and multiply by 2 then + 1 the same number of times, you’ll get remainder =0 again and all the rest will have remainders. Ho do I say this in math speak?

Comment: I guess you mean the proof of $p|q-1$. We assume that $p$ does not divide $q-1$.Then, we can write $q-1=ap+b$ with $0<b<p$. We can conclude that $2^b\equiv 1\mod q$, which contradicts that the smallest such positive integer is $p$.

Comment: So is it proven now then?

Comment: Yes, the proof is finished with this argument. Not quite sure whether your argument is rigorous as well, maybe you try to formulate your try more precisely.